# SSJS Try/Catch Behaving Different in Different MIDs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect

For context, I have two different Marketing Cloud orgs, one that we will call PROD and one that we will call UAT. They are completely separate. They are each connected to a Salesforce instance, PROD is connected to a Production Salesforce.com instance, UAT is connected to a full-copy sandbox of the Production Salesforce.com instance.

Given the below code:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  try {
</script>
%%[
  CreateSalesforceObject("Contact", 2, "FirstName", "Test", "LastName", "Testerson")
]%%
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
  } catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

If I run this code in PROD, no error is printed to the screen, instead the familiar 500 - Internal Server Error page is displayed. However, in UAT, an error is displayed matching a validation rule on the Contact. This UAT behavior is the behavior that should be occurring in both environments.

```
{
  "message": "The function expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.\r\n Script: CreateSalesforceObject(\"Contact\", 2, \"FirstName\", \"Test\", \"LastName\", \"Testerson\")\r\n Index: 1545\r\n ListID: 0\r\n",
  "description": "ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException: The function expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.\r\n Script: CreateSalesforceObject(\"Contact\", 2, \"FirstName\", \"Test\", \"LastName\", \"Testerson\")\r\n Index: 1545\r\n ListID: 0\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXPR_INVALID\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: Call to create the salesforceobject Contact failed! Error status code: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION\nError message: The customer must provide either a Phone number or an Email address!\r\n Error Code: CREATESFOJBECT_FUNC_ERROR\r\n - from SalesforceFunctionHandler\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
}
```

Does anyone know what is different between the two MIDs or between the two Salesforce instances (some object or app setting, for example) that would cause this difference in behavior?

Comment: I would contact SF Support as if its the same code, it should function the same. Across all the accounts I have seen, I have not run into this issue before so I am guessing it is likely some business rule somewhere or similar 'behind the scenes' setting that was turned on in one context but not the other - which is causing the difference in output

Comment: Reaching out now, and will follow up with results when I get them.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a custom setting made on the SF object in the UAT Sales Cloud which is not (yet?) copied to your Prod org. `FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION\nError message: The customer must provide either a Phone number or an Email address!` -> This reads like a custom rule developed on the object. can you ensure that both orgs have the same rules when creating contacts? what happens if you try manually?

Comment: The validation exists on the object in both orgs. This is just a short example code to get the concept of the problem across. The more exact problem is that when the Salesforce function is surrounded by a try/catch block, PROD still results in a 500 whereas UAT honors the try/catch. This is always the case for Salesforce functions, but not for all ampscript functions.